# Where to initialize jobs in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've created some ActiveJobs that I would like to start right when the application server is started. I've been having difficulty finding a place to initialize these jobs. Is there a location similar to a main method in rails?

Comment: How about in `config/initializers`? 'Cause, those are for, you know, initializing.

Comment: Yes, put anything that you want to happen on application startup in the initializers.

Comment: Can you give an example what kind of jobs you want to start with the server? Because in a common production setup there might be more than one server, each with multiple processes. Would it be okay to start duplicate Jobs at the same time when deploying the application? What if processes stop and restart depending on server load should that trigger new jobs too? This feels like a [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/284887) to me.

Comment: @jvillian Seems that those files also get run during rake which i am trying to avoid

Comment: I did [this googlie](https://www.google.com/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=rails+don%27t+run+initializers+on+rake&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8) and it looks like there are a number of SO Q&As on this topic. Have you reviewed them all?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can put it inside your application.rb config file like this

```
config.after_initialize do
# Your code
end
```

config.after_initialize takes a block which will be run **after** Rails has finished initializing the application.